# Design an Algorithm for counting the number of 1's in an Array A n x n

Tags: algorithm

Suppose that each row of an `n x n` array `A` consists of 1's and 0's such that, in any row i of `A` , all the 1's come before any 0's in that row.Suppose further that the number of 1's in row i is at least the number in row `i + 1`, for `i = 0,1,2,....,n-2`
Assuming A is already in memory , describe a method running in `O(n)` time for counting the number of 1's in the array `A`.

So my approach is to start at `A[n-1,0]` if == 1 we add number of 1's else we go up and right
so we scan A moving only to the right and upwards

Comment: Homework? What have you tried? Did it work?

Comment: Your approach is correct, where is the problem?

Comment: i only need a while loop then ? not 2 loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-loop:

```
SUM = 0
j = 0
for i from n-1 to 0 step -1 do {
  while (j<n)and(A[i,j]==1) do {
    j = j+1
  }
  SUM = SUM+j
}
```

One-loop:

```
SUM = 0
i = n-1
j = 0
while (i>=0)and(j<n) do {
  if A[i,j]==1 then {
    j = j+1
  } else {
    SUM = SUM+j
    i = i-1
  }
}
```